# Por qué se duplican mis tablas SQLite en android utilizando execSQL() en un bucle, pero no cuando lo declaro normal?

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Este es mi bucle con mi lista de queries que crean las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obtengo el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porqué no verificas si ya existe la tabla antes de crear? con `IF EXISTS`